# What is this obsolete (?) video screw connector called?

Tags: identification, connector, video, vintage

Found on the rear of an old (1970s) Sanyo monitor. It's not standard cable/co-ax, it's larger and beefier. It's used here for a composite signal.

[image]

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: That connector is not obsolete - it is commonly used as an antenna connector on CB and VHF marine radios.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like an [SO239 UHF connector.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UHF_connector)

That's the socket that goes with the PL259 plug.

---

The term "UHF connector" is somewhat misleading.

It was developed in the 1930s.  Back then, UHF meant "over 30MHz."  These days, [UHF is 300 MHz to 3GHz.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra_high_frequency)

Comment: For a discussion of how far SO239 is from being a modern-meaning UHF connector: [an answer on ham.stackexchange.com](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/13061/pl-259-so-239-vs-n-type-vs-bnc-which-is-best-connector-to-use-when/13062#13062).

Comment: True. I had it on my marine VHF and CB, but the antenna and cable was 50 ohm (RG-58).  You can see on the case that is meant to connect a 75 ohm impedance. As @MarcusMüller say in other post, this connector probably doesn't meet a 50 nor 75 ohm characteristics impedance, they just made a connector as is.

Comment: My oscilloscope (built in 1965) has SO239 sockets.  The original probes had PL259 plugs on them.  I use BNC to SO239 adapters and modern oscilloscope probes.

Comment: Nice thing about SO239, you can stick banana plugs in the center pin. Other than that, horrible connector.

Comment: My brand-new HF radio (3–50MHz) uses this connector for the antenna.

Comment: I could have sworn that in the UK these were called *"UNC connectors"* (as opposed to BNC connectors), or sometimes *"N connectors"*, but I cannot find any evidence to back this up (hence this is not an answer).

Comment: @abligh:  [The N connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_connector) is a different beast entirely.

Comment: @JRE you are entirely right. UNC is I think what I remembered (connecting an old monitor to a BBC micro I think required a UNC to BNC lead). Perhaps I just had the wrong name.

Comment: I had one of these on the back of a CCTV monitor which expected a standard (although monochrome) PAL basebase video signal. Nothing more than 6MHz, so I'm not sure why it has that connector.